# How to disable button in PHP using JQUERY?

Tags: jquery, button

I have a button in my application :

```
<button name="download" id="download" type="submit" class="btn primary" style="margin:0;">Next</button>
```

How can I disable this button and re-enable it using JQuery ?

I tried below code but it doesn't works.

```
$('#download').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 $('#download').removeAttr('disabled');
```

TIA :)

Comment: when u need to disable ?

Comment: your code is [working](http://jsfiddle.net/rLx46rqj/) ... make sure you have only one element inside DOM with id `download`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[ 
      $(window).load(function(){
        $('button#download').prop('disabled', true);
        alert('hello');
        $('button#download').removeAttr('disabled');
      });
    //]]>  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button name="download" id="download" type="submit" class="btn primary" style="margin:0;">Next</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code if you have text box that is `empty` the submit button ill be disbaled if the textbox is not `empty` submit button not disabled

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
         $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
         $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
            if($(this).val() != '') {
               $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
         });
     });
```